# MySQL Error: "Unknown table engine 'InnoDBopt'"

Tags: php, mysql, database, wamp

I'm getting the following error on some code from an old app:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1286

Unknown table engine 'InnoDBopt'

INSERT INTO `sessions` (`session_id`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`, `last_activity`) VALUES ('2ef196aba7f060308be6b7bc1133671f', '127.0.0.1', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) Ap', 1290342372)
```

I'm using MySQL version 5.1.36. This app was developed a while ago, so most likely I just need to downgrade my MySQL version to run this? If so, please advise what version I need to run this.

**Edit:** To clarify, I had to copy my database from one mysql installation to another, so I copied everything inside `c:/mysql/data' to the other installation of MySQL, that's likely what's causing this issue.

Comment: This sounds like a broken table engine definition: There's not a single Google hit for `InnoDBopt`. What does a SHOW CREATE say?

Comment: First to check is your new wamp support mysql innodb. Second, try `mysqldump` to load data into the new setup

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the mysql user can write to /tmp. I got 'Unknown table engine `InnoDB`' after restore where /tmp was not writable for that user.

Answer (score 2):

There is another reason  why INNODB engine is absent from MySQL. If your innodb_buffer_pool_size variable is too high and MySQL can't allocate the buffer it will disable the INNODB engine.

You should see something like this in the error log :

```
140204 13:12:26  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 4.9G
140204 13:12:26  InnoDB: Error: cannot allocate 5242896384 bytes of
InnoDB: memory with malloc! Total allocated memory
InnoDB: by InnoDB 36878736 bytes. Operating system errno: 12
InnoDB: Check if you should increase the swap file or
InnoDB: ulimits of your operating system.
InnoDB: On FreeBSD check you have compiled the OS with
InnoDB: a big enough maximum process size.
InnoDB: Note that in most 32-bit computers the process
InnoDB: memory space is limited to 2 GB or 4 GB.
InnoDB: We keep retrying the allocation for 60 seconds...
140204 13:13:26InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate the memory for the buffer pool
140204 13:13:26 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140204 13:13:26 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
```

This error was logged on a server with 1GB of RAM while the buffer pool request 4.9G

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Pekka, there is no engine 'InnoDBopt'

Try `show engines;`

If mysql return something like

`+------------+----------+----

| Engine     | Support  | ...

+------------+----------+----

| InnoDB     | DISABLED | ...`

Most likely engine innodb has been disabled.
Look for option `skip-innodb` in your mysql configuration (such as my.cnf),
comment out this option,
restart mysql daemon, it should fix

Comment: If you installed Mysql from sources you forget this option `--with-innodb` or is something wrong with your configuration file

Comment: I installed WAMP and that installed MySQL for me. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

where is the table engine define? in my.cnf? check the spelling in my.cnf ... "opt" sounds like a path to a log file or something defined in the config file.

Comment: that's likely, where is this listed in my my.cnf?

Comment: search for `my.cnf` ... prob in /etc or something.

Comment: I've got the my.cnf file, what should I look for inside that file?

Answer (score 0):

Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE sessions`
and then run 
`SHOW engines`

You will see something like 
ENGINE=xyz at he end of the first command result

xyz has to be in the list returned by SHOW engines

Edit:
To be more explicit: The result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE sessions` is somethig like:

`Table: sessions
Create Table: CREATE TABLE sessions (
................
) ENGINE=xyz`

where xyz could be MyIssam , Innodb, etc.

Comment: When i run the 1st query i get '#1286 - Unknown table engine 'InnoDB'
'.

Comment: read about #1286 - Unknown table engine 'InnoDB' error here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,150623,150822